# How to use BrowserRouter and Route in CodeSandbox React JS?

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

I'm trying to use BrowserRouter and Router in my ReactJS project at CodeSandbox and there is a dependency error: Could not find dependency: 'react-router-dom' relative to '/src/App.js'
I don't know how to control these dependencies yet. Please Help!

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Comment: You will need to install dependencies on the mid-left corner of the page. that should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add React-router-dom from **Add dependenc**y.[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Codesandbox  and you want to use third party package you need to add that third party package as a dependecy of your project which can be done under the `Dependencies` Section of the left side `Explorer` for that package to be available in your code so you can import that package